# Cannot authorize with LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the **first name, surname and email** from a user on my website with LinkedIn. This is what I've done:

In my LinkedIn App I've set the **Default Scope** (OAuth User Agreement) to:

- r_basicprofile
- r_contactinfo
- w_share
- r_emailaddress

I've correctly added my domain to **Javascript API Domains**. I didn't add a link to OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs. But I don't know if that's mandatory (and which path to insert)?

I've also **copied** my **API Key** (Consumer Key).

Now in my HTML I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    lang: en_US
    api_key: myapikey
    scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
</script>

<input class="apply-with-linkedin" type="button" value="Apply with LinkedIn" id="btn-linkedin-apply">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#btn-linkedin-apply').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        IN.User.authorize(function ()
        {
            IN.API.Profile('me').fields([
                'firstName',
                'lastName',
                'emailAddress'
            ]).result(function (profiles)
            {
                var me = profiles.values[0];

                if (me.hasOwnProperty('firstName')) {
                    jQuery('#apply-form #input-firstname').val(me.firstName);
                }

                if (me.hasOwnProperty('lastName')) {
                    jQuery('#apply-form #input-lastname').val(me.lastName);
                }

                if (me.hasOwnProperty('emailAddress')) {
                    jQuery('#apply-form #input-email').val(me.emailAddress);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But I always get the javascript error `Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined` when I click the button. The `IN.User` is undefined.

What could be wrong with this? ...

**UPDATE:**

The javascript code where I specify my API Key, ... I've copied from the ["Getting Started with the JavaScript SDK" from LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key:   [API_KEY]
  onLoad:    [ONLOAD]
  authorize: [AUTHORIZE]
  lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
</script>
```

Comment: @JeremyThille: I've added an update to my topic. Could you take a look?

Comment: @JeremyThille, Then why are they placing this in the Getting Started topic??

Comment: Jeremy - the documentation is correct, and you are also correct that this is obviously not standard Javascript notation.The content within the <script> tags is parsed by LinkedIn using the new-lines and name:value pairs as described.

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that you are just experiencing problems with the asynchronicity of the library.  I've modified the sample code from the [Sign in with LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin) Javascript example slightly for you, but I think your issue will be solved with paying more attention to the callbacks so that you know a) the library is loaded, and b) the API call has successfully completed - before attempting to access any of the resulting data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    authorize: true
    scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        // Pre-populate your form fields here once you know the call 
        // came back successfully
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(firstName,lastName,emailAddress)").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>
```